# Regex in php not matching where it should

Tags: php, regex

I have tried to make a regex I use with php evolve, but by adding an additional one-character group, the regex no longer finds any matches.

Previous version was:

```
$pattern = '{\{[0-9]+[a-z][0,1][0,1]\}}';
```

matching strings like {010c10} or {009c10}.

I then decided to make the strings to be matched evolve by adding a [0,1] character, adapting the regex as follows:

```
$pattern = '{\{[0-9]+[a-z][0,1][0,1][0,1]\}}';
```

However, the regex now no longer matches strings like {010c100}
, and I really cannot see why.

Comment: I'd use `{\{[0-9]+[a-z][01]{3}\}}` in your case as i'm unaware of the syntax and meaning of comma-separated chars in the square brackets.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the pattern and testing? like so: `$pattern = '{\{[0-9]+[a-z][0,1]\}}';`

Comment: A quick test shows it does match... How are you matching your string?

Comment: Works fine in Java (also mostly compatible with PERL), I think there is something you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please **add your PHP code that performs the matching** to your posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// match short versions, such as {010c10}
$pattern = '/\{\d+[a-z][0,1]{2}\}/'; 

// match long versions, such as {010c100}
$pattern = '/\{\d+[a-z][0,1]{3}\}/'; 

// match short and/or long versions
$pattern = '/\{\d+[a-z][0,1]{2,3}\}/';
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `\{\d+[a-z][01]{3}\}`

Comment: OK, you've simplified the regular expression, but how would that help against mismatches?